# Looking for a movie alt series with giants on bikes in the world's core

Tags: story-identification

I have a vague memory of a movie or a series where an adventurer travel to the core of the earth (or another world, I don't remember), where he/she/they find giants riding on bicycles to make the world spin. I don't remember much more than that, I think one of the giants disappeared? Making the world stand still? Any help would be great, I've searched for days now

Comment: Can you remember any more details? Such as where you saw the film? The language? When you may have seen it? This [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) may be of help.